# How do I cast an XAML item in its controller? [C#],[Xamarin.Forms]

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin and I'm facing a problem when it comes to use a xaml item (A button or Label for example) in the controller of this .xaml file.

I just dont know how to declare the item inside the controller, for example in java we use something like

```cs
Button btnSave = (Button) findViewByID(R.xmlFILE.btnSave);
```

then we can use the "btnSave" as an object inside the class controller, but when it comes to Xamarin.forms, I just cant seem to find how I do that, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in XAML, assign a name to the control

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" ... />
```

then in your xaml.cs file, you just refer to it by name.  You don't need to declare it or cast it

```
myButton.Text = "blah";
```

Comment: aight Jason, that's what I did, i assigned a name to the item:                           <Button x:Name="btnSave"  Text="Press me" />                                                                                                               but still, the .cs file cannot find it and I get this error:  the name "btnSave" does not exist  in the context

Comment: the corresponding xaml.cs file, or some other .cs file?

Comment: the one who has the same file name, but with .cs at its end

Comment: @PedroLeal do a clean/rebuild.